# wxWidgets 3.1.6, wxAuiNotebook Font Problems

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I just upgraded to wxWidgets 3.1.6 and it seems there are loads of fixes and upgrades. However, I ran into the problem of rather small font size for notebook page text.

I am using `wxAuiNotebook` to host `CWorksheet` a class derived from `wxGrid`. The notebook constructs as follows:

```
CWorksheetNotebook::CWorksheetNotebook(CWorkbook* parent) :
        wxAuiNotebook(parent, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxAUI_NB_DEFAULT_STYLE), m_Workbook{ parent }
    {    
        SetFont(wxFont(11, wxFONTFAMILY_SWISS, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wxFONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, false, "Arial"));
        ....
        //SetMeasuringFont, SetNormalFont does not have any effect
    }
```

Then to add a Worksheet to the notebook:

```
auto panel = new wxPanel(this);
auto sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

auto varGrid = new CWorksheet(panel, m_Workbook, WSLabel, nrows, ncols);

sizer->Add(varGrid, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 5);
panel->SetSizer(sizer);

AddPage(panel, WSLabel, true);
```

Here, if I manually set the font (as in the constructor) the page text font changes to a larger one but then I have another problem arising from setting the font manually. *Setting the font of wxAuiNotebook changes Column and Row labels fonts in `CWorksheet`*.

The worksheet implements the virtual methods from wxGrid:

```
void DrawColLabel(wxDC& dc, int col) override;

void DrawColLabels(wxDC& dc, const wxArrayInt& cols) override;

//Similarly for Rows
```

The implementation of DrawColLabel is:

```
wxPen InitialPen = dc.GetPen();
wxBrush InitialBrush = dc.GetBrush();

wxRect Rect(GetColLeft(col), 0, GetColWidth(col), GetColLabelSize());


wxBrush brush;
brush.SetColour(wxColor(224, 224, 224));
brush.SetStyle(wxBRUSHSTYLE_SOLID);

dc.SetBrush(brush);
dc.DrawRectangle(Rect);

dc.SetTextForeground(wxColor(0, 102, 0));
dc.DrawLabel(GetColLabelValue(col), Rect, wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL);



dc.SetPen(wxPen(wxColor(0, 255, 0), 3));
dc.DrawLine(Rect.GetBottomLeft(), Rect.GetBottomRight());


dc.SetPen(InitialPen);
dc.SetBrush(InitialBrush);
```

I did not have the problem of small fonts when using wxWidgets 3.1.4. I am using Visual Studio 2022 (14.2 for compiler) on Windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it on regular or HighDPI monitor? What is you resolution? Can you make a small repro example or a patch to auidemo showing an issue?

Comment: Or maybe even do a bisect of the tree to find a broken commit...

Comment: Current settings are 1920x1080 and 125% scaling. The problem continues to happen even when scaling changes, say, to 150%.

Comment: Maybe using [SetOwnFont](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a89a4f62f23c1e7c845b8d07cecae4c43) instead of `SetFont` would prevent changing the labels.

Comment: @NewPagodi, thanks it worked!! Spent a few hours trying to figure out how to fix this...